# Where to get cross-linker?

Tags: llvm, clang, ld

I found that providing few options to llvm-clang I can compile to other platform. This for example will compile for ios:

`clang -cc1 -triple arm-apple-darwin -emit-obj -mrelax-all -disable-free -main-file-name six.c -pic-level 1 -mdisable-fp-elim -masm-verbose -target-abi apcs-gnu -target-cpu arm7tdmi -msoft-float -mfloat-abi soft -target-feature +soft-float -target-feature +soft-float-abi -target-feature -neon  -ferror-limit 1 -fmessage-length 122 -stack-protector 1 -mstackrealign -fblocks -fsjlj-exceptions  -fcolor-diagnostics prog.c -o -c`

As a result you get the prog.o, which you need to copy to native platform and link with native ld. But object file is already compiled for that platform!

Now the last step is to avoid using native linker on the remote. I need a cross-linker for that. But where to get one? Or does llvm contain one and I just need to use the right options? Or I need to compoile GNU LD with the support of cross-platform? From my experience, compiling LD is not possible without expert knowledge of it.

Answer (score 2):

I have versions of the gnu tools that I use with clang at http://ellcc.org. I build under Linux (you didn't mention a host OS). I build assemblers, ld and other utilities, as well as gdb to support the ARM, i386, Microblaze, Mips, PowerPC, PowerPC64, and X86_64. The cool thing about my build is that I take advantage of the GNU tools ability to be compiled to support multiple targets. **ld**, **gdb**, and most of the utilites support all the processors. Only **as** needs a separate binary for each target.